# C++ Concept: How to define this circular-dependent constraint?

Tags: c++, c++20, circular-dependency, type-traits, concept

I have two classes `Communication` and `Handler`. `Communication` is templated with the `Handler` it will use.

```cpp
template<HandlerLike THandler>
struct Communication;
```

where `HandlerLike` is a `Handler` that can be constructed with `this` of the `Communication`. i.e., for a satisfied `Handler`, the constructor `Handler(Communication<Handler>* parent)` should be available.

Since `HandlerLike` was used by `Communication` and also referencing `Communication`, it is defined circularly.

I tried to use type trait to split the concept definition and implementation using the following code. But it did not compile due to unsatisfied constraint. I wonder why this did not work and how to correct it. Thank you!

```cpp
#include <concepts>

// Forward declaration of handler type trait
template<typename THandler>
struct is_handler_like;

template<typename THandler>
concept HandlerLike = is_handler_like<THandler>::value;

/// The pointer to the communication object will be stored in the handlers for future reference.
template<HandlerLike THandler>
struct Communication {};


template<typename THandler>
constexpr bool value = requires(
        THandler obj,
        Communication<THandler> *parent
) {
    // THandler should be constructed with the parent pointer.
    { THandler(parent) };
};

// Deferred implementation of is_handler_like
template<typename THandler>
struct is_handler_like : public std::bool_constant<value> {
};


// A dummy handler implementation. 
struct DummyHandler {
    Communication<DummyHandler> *parent{};

    // The constructor should have satisfied the constraint, but the compiler says no. 
    explicit DummyHandler(Communication<DummyHandler> *parent) : parent(parent) {}
};

int main() {
    Communication<DummyHandler> comm;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Circular dependencies are a root of all evil in a software. If `A` depended on `B` and vice versa, then proper solution is to introduce `C` which `A` and `B` depend on and this way break one dependency between `A` and `B`.

Comment: @MarekR I agree. Could you provide some suggestion how I can decouple this design to prevent circular dependencies?

Comment: @YuanyiWu: To do that, we'd have to know what the intent behind these types are.

Comment: @NicolBolas For simplicity I stripped the requirements off the question. My intent was to have the `Communication` to receive and send data. The `Handler` is used to process the incoming message and optionally send data back. To send data back I need to keep a reference to the `Communication`.

Answer (score 3):

A concept cannot constrain a definition that it references. That is semantically nonsensical.

When you encounter problems like this, it's best to take a step back and ask why the circular dependency exists. Evaluate whether it is truly necessary for `Handler` to be intimately related to `Communication` and vice-versa. And then evaluate whether there is something that can be pulled out of these two types into its own thing, upon which the remainder of the other two can depend but is not itself dependent on them.

This is a design problem, not a language problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my intent to use this design in the question comments. I could not figure out how to extract a common part if I want to store the Communication` as a pointer reference in the `Handler` object. Do you have some suggestion to decouple this?

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about c++20:

```
//common concept
template <typename H>
concept HandlerLike = requires(H handler) {
    { handler.read()  };
    { handler.write() };
};

template <typename H, typename C>
concept Handler = 
(HandlerLike<H> && HandlerLike<C>) //H and C are HandlerLike
&& requires (H handler, C *comm) {
    { handler.setCommunication(comm) }; //requires the handler to set the communication obj
};

template <typename C, typename H>
concept Communication = 
(HandlerLike<C> && Handler<H,C>) //C is HandlerLike and H is Handler
&& requires (C comm, H *handler) {
    { C(handler) }; // requires handler constructor
};
```

Afterwards, implement your classes, so that they match the specific concepts.